# Database Design for Games Attended

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I go to a lot of sports games, mostly hockey. I have been tracking the games via an excel sheet and even at one point a simple database table. I am trying to build this a little better and eventually create a web interface. But I also want to be able to run various queries.

I don't care about player goals, ice-time, sog or any of those stats - merely just teams playing, score and date with a section for notes. (eg, Hat trick, 500th game for player)

So what I had was:

(id, home_team, home_score, away_team, away_score, jersey = [home,away,alt], date, notes, timestamp)

I have thought of other ways to normalize it but I don't want to over complicate it and trying to query has been a nightmare.

I had a three table design in mind:

## Team

(team_id, city, state, nickname)

## League

(league_id, league_name, conference, division)

## Venue

(venue_id, venue_name, venue_city, venue_state, venue_zip, venue_address, venue_capacity)

Venue table and even league table seem unnecessary for the most part but I was thinking of different types of queries.

Then I would create some views or a games table that would pull in the necessary fields.

Queries I had in mind to execute:

1. Games attended that the home team won
2. How many times my team has played whatever team and overall record
3. Games won/lost wearing alternate jersey, home jersey, away jersey
4. Venues visited and record when visiting
5. Games attended where there has been a significant event. (Hat trick, record)
6. Overall record of games attended in x year, all time.
7. Playoff game record, preseason game record, regular season record (I was thinking I could notate game type in notes or create a field for type and do (playoff, preseason, regular)

Any advice would be appreciated, its not that I do not know how to build the database, it is that I do not know how to build it right and without stressing over the entire website I want to build from it.

Eventually I would like to expand it to other sporting events (football, baseball, basketball, etc..) but before getting too far ahead of myself I would like to get the hockey one running.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well for one right now your three tables don't connect to each other.  Are they supposed to?  For instance I imagine each team is part of a league?  So in Team you might want to add a field that stores league_id so you could join it to the League table.  Likewise with Venue which I assume also should connect to Team?

Comment: If I was to use those three tables, I think there is some data I don't really need in them, I would have yet another table tying them all together called games.

Home_Team = team_id, Home_score, Away_team = team_id, Away_score, Location = Venue_id, League=league_id, date, notes and timestamp

But yeah, that was kind of what I was thinking. I just feel like the one table model I have is too repetitive when all the home games are the same team mostly, but not always.

Comment: I don't know enough about hockey but it seems like you might end up needlessly duplicating data that way.  For instance, if you know the teams playing the game, shouldn't you know the league without having to store it in a Games table every time?  Or can teams be in more than one league?  Likewise if you know the home team doesn't that also tell you the venue?  Or do teams play home games in a variety of venues?

Comment: Good point -- after further analysis all I really need to collect is: 

(id, home_team, home_score, away_team, away_score, date, jersey, notes,  timestamp)

I guess the only real duplication will be with the home_team mostly and jersey because most of them will be home

With that data, 1 table works fine for the most part, and it will make entering it via a web-form a lot easier but is this ideal? There will be instances where I go to a minor league game so it wont always be NHL but there will be different team names and easily identifiable.
I don't even need jersey, I can put that in notes